# Conditional breakpoint error: Attempting to pass a lambda to a delegate C# in VS 2019, alternative

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019, conditional-breakpoint

I read that this was a product error and it seems to be coming back again and again. I could tick the option to "Use managed compatibility mode", however if I do so, I can't use linq in the Immediate windows, which I need. Editing the code in the file, is what I want to avoid at all cost.

[image]

The code I'm currently using in the conditional breakpoint is below (it doesn't work either), where Services is a string IEnumerable. The breakpoint is placed after the line that assigns values to Services. The error shows up when the condition effectively is true, that is, Services.Count() is greater than 0. After the error message, the breakpoint never stops the program execution again.

```
html.Services.Count() > 0
```

It is an Azure job and the structure of my code is:

```
namespace myNamespace
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public async Task Handle(RefreshCommand command)
        {
            await anArrayLoaded.ForEachAsync(async item =>
            {
                try
                {
                    html.Services = LoadingServices(item);
```

Comment: Based on my search, I find that wrong code may cause the problem. Therefore, can you possibly provide the related code so that we can test it?

Comment: @Jack J Jun - MSFT I added more details to the question. I cannot add the source code, however.